how to duplicate PECL PHP interactive shell with PHPSecLib
I want to duplicate the functionality of PECL PHP interactive shell function ssh2_shell() using PHPSecLib.  How would I do that?  I see that openShell() was recently exposed as a public function but I don't see any examples how to use that.  I am wondering if that is what I need to use. It's not as simple as doing ssh->write() because it's a constant stream that needs to stay open.  Polling is also not an option.  I did that before with PHPSecLib and it doesn't work nearly as well as ssh2_shell(), which is a constant stream.  Not sure if that is the correct terminology.
Here is the ssh2_shell() function that I am currently using and would like to try duplicate with PHPSecLib so that I can migrate completely away from using libssh.
/**
     * SSH2 shell getter.  For Ratchet stream console
     *
     * @param [type] $session
     * @param string $termType
     * @param [type] $env
     * @param string $width
     * @param string $height
     * @param string $widthHeightType
     * @return void
     */
    public function getShell($termType = 'vanilla', $env = null, $width = 80, $height = 25, $widthHeightType = SSH2_TERM_UNIT_CHARS)
    {
        return ssh2_shell($this->ssh, $termType, $env, $width, $height, $widthHeightType);
    }

This is for a realtime PHP streaming console using Ratchet.  My code is based on this project.
https://github.com/roke22/PHP-SSH2-Web-Client
I would also like to try duplicate the functionality of ssh2_shell_resize(), which lets me changes the shell size on the fly.  That is a fairly new function that was added to PHP PECL SSH2 v1.4

You don't need to use openShell() to make use of interactive shells with phpseclib. If you're going to be using an interactive shell whilst running a command with $ssh->exec() then that's where openShell() comes into play. https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/1888 talks about it more. But if you're not doing that then maybe https://phpseclib.com/docs/commands#read--write might be a useful example.

Tha said, if you want to the width and height of the shell with phpseclib you can do $ssh->setWindowColumns($value) and $ssh->setWindowRows($value).

I don't think that is what I am looking for.  This is a console application.  Literally duplicating Linux CLI.  So I need to actually run the commands within the active stream.  Interactve shell the way PHPSecLib uses it sends a command then waits for a response.  I did it before using PHPSecLib using a while loop.  I guess I should go find that code and post that.  But that is not as good as using ssh2_shell() which is what I am doing now.  So if PHPSecLib can do what I want, it would be with something that may have been added recently.  As in maybe the last 2 or 3 years.

I don't think setWindowColumns() and Rows() lets me change that on the fly inside an active stream.  Just imagine running a PuTTy Linux CLI console on your desktop.  When you resize the window, the streamed data over the SSH connection resizes.  That is what I want to do with PHP on a browser.  I do that exact thing right now using ssh2_shell() and ssh2_shell_resize() and using PHP Ratchet for the real time connection.  Similar to that github project link I posted.  I think it may be harder for PHPSecLib to try do that because it's not using an underlying c library that has that functionality.
